# Proving the chain rule using the sequential definition of derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, proof-verification

I have seen many proofs using the normal derivative definition, but I was wondering if the same result could be achieved using the sequential definition which states:

> If $f$ is a function and has derivative $f'(c)$ at the point $c$ in the domain of $f$ means that if ($x_n$)$_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is any sequence converging to $c$ such that $x_n$ $\not= c$ is in the domain of $f$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N},$ then: $$\left[ \frac{f(x_n)-f(c)}{x_n-c}\right]_{n=1}^{\infty}$$ converges to $f'(c)$

My attempt:

If $g$ is a differentiable function at $x=c,$ and $f$ is differentiable at $x=g(c),$ then $f(g(x))$ is differentiable at $x=c$ and $f(g(x))'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$

Since $g$ is differentiable at $x=c,$ $$\left[ \frac{g(x_n)-g(c)}{x_n-c}\right]_{n=1}^{\infty} \to g'(c)~.$$ 
Since $f$ is differentiable at $x=g(c),$ $$\left[ \frac{f(g(x_n))-f(g(c))}{g(x_n)-g(c)}\right]_{n=1}^{\infty}  \to f'(g(c))~.$$ 
Therefore $$\left[ \frac{f(g(x_n))-f(g(c))}{x_n-c}\right]_{n=1}^{\infty} \iff \left( \frac{f(g(x_n))-f(g(c))}{g(x_n)-g(c)}\right)\left( \frac{g(x_n)-g(c)}{x_n-c}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}~.$$

Thus $f(g(c))'=f'(g(c))g'(c)$

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this because I am simply multiplying by $\displaystyle\left( \frac{g(x_n)-g(c)}{g(x_n)-g(c)}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ which is technically $1$, so any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: $$\left[ \frac{f(g(x_n))-f(g(c))}{g(x_n)-g(c)}\right]_{n=1}^{\infty} \to f'(g(c))$$

Comment: @WW1 What do you mean?

Comment: I think that is what you meant to write instead of $\left[ \frac{f(g(x_n))-f(g(c))}{x_n-c}\right]_{n=1}^{\infty} \to f'(c)$

Comment: Yes, thank you! @WW1

Comment: @WW1 Would this proof still be right after making that adjustment?

Comment: But there is an issue if g(x(n))=g(c). 0/0 is undefined.

Comment: There is a part of the definition I forgot to mention. But we assume that $g(x(n)) \not= g(c)$